# Tomcat Strange Re-direct accessing Application

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

I have a Java Spring application packaged up in a .WAR file that I'm trying to deploy with Tomcat 8. I've added the `myapp.war` to the `webapps` directory in Tomcat. It seems to start perfectly fine but when I try to access the application on `0.0.0.0:8080/myapp` it attempts the re-direct to the login page but appends another myapp to the url (`0.0.0.0:8080/myapp/myapp`) and throws me a HTTP 404 saying that the login page resource can't be found.

Can anyone suggest some reasons why I might be experiencing this odd re-direct behaviour?

Comment: Post the details of web.xml and spring-config.xml files

Comment: There is quite a lot of it. Are there any relevant parts that you are looking for?

Comment: I'm looking for view resolver, servlet mapping, welcome page entries.